# Display Two Images On Submit Using Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, file-upload

Suppose I have two div boxes as shown below :

[image]

So What I did is when I click on submit Button the image gets uploaded on the no Image Section.
But What I also want that When I click the button one time . the Image should be loaded on both the boxes .

This is my HTML  :

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-6">
      <h2 class="inputImage-text text-center">Input Image</h2>
       <form id="uploadForm" action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       <div id="targetLayer">No Image</div>
       <div id="uploadFormLayer">
       <input name="fileToUpload" type="file" class="inputFile" /><br/>
       <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btnSubmit btn btn-primary" />
       </div>
       </form>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">

      <h2 class="outputImage-text text-center">Output Image</h2>

    </div>


   </div>
</div>
```

Here is my AJAX Script :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $("#uploadForm").on('submit',(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: "upload.php",
            type: "POST",
            data:  new FormData(this),

            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData:false,
            success: function(data)
            {
            $("#targetLayer").html(data);

            },
            error: function() 
            {
            }           
       });
    }));
});
</script>
```

And Here is my Php code for Loading

```
<?php
if(is_array($_FILES)) {
if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['filetoUpload']['tmp_name'])) {
$sourcePath = $_FILES['filetoUpload']['tmp_name'];
$targetPath = "images/".$_FILES['filetoUpload']['name'];
if(move_uploaded_file($sourcePath,$targetPath)) {
?>
<img class="image-preview" src="<?php echo $targetPath; ?>" class="upload-preview" />
<?php
}
}
}
?>
```

Comment: you r not echo your image in php

Comment: your question is still open, are you still searching? if not then accept the best answer the close this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all pass datatype `html` in ajax request as `dataType: "html",`

Then, if you want to load image in `<div id="targetLayer">No Image</div>` then you must need to `echo` image from PHP script like:

```
echo '<img src="<?php echo $targetPath; ?>" />';
```

if you want to load image in both boxes then create one another `div` here:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
<h2 class="outputImage-text text-center">Output Image</h2>
<div id="boxTwo"></div>
</div>
```

and in jQuery, use this:

```
$("#targetLayer").html(data);
$("#boxTwo").html(data);
```

And, i have no idea why are you using 2 classes `class="image-preview"` and `class="upload-preview"` in `<img>` tag?

In last, you have one typo also in your code, you are using `name="fileToUpload"` but in php you are fetching the record with `$_FILES['filetoUpload']` which will give you **UNDEFINED INDEX NOTICE**

Comment: I get your answer, But If I want to show different Image on the other box on the same AJAX Command. Can I do that ?

Comment: @AbnitChauhan: yes why not, if you are getting 2 images from php script then you can use array for both images and print with json_encode but in ajax you must need to define datatype = json

Answer (score 0):

You can use class name instead of using id of the div to show the results in both using jQuery.

```
   $(".targetLayer").html(data);

<div id="targetLayer" class="targetLayer">No Image</div>
<h2 class="outputImage-text text-center targetLayer">Output Image</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create `<div id="outputLayer"></div>` after `<h2 class="outputImage-text text-center">Output Image</h2>` and replace `$("#targetLayer").html(data);` with `$("#targetLayer").add('#outputLayer').html(data);`

Comment: U are right . I can use the same html(data). for the other box. But what If I want to add the different image in the other div box.

Comment: @AbnitChauhan: u can do it, but question is that, from where you are getting the second image?

Comment: I am processing the image through python script and getting the variable . that will include in src the python code will work fine but only problem is how can I process both the images from single Ajax Script ? @devpro

Comment: @AbnitChauhan: u are only loading 1 image from your script, where is second image? plz add in your question